# How to set the number of Decimal places in Plotly violin hover_text

Tags: python-3.x, plotly, plotly-python

I have a working Plotly violin plot but the hover_text gives my a lot of decimal places. Is it possible to set the number of decimal places (preferably 2).

This is a full working code from the Plotly webiste, but it illustrates my problem.

```
import plotly.graph_objects as go

import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/plotly/datasets/master/violin_data.csv")

fig = go.Figure(data=go.Violin(y=df['total_bill'], box_visible=True, line_color='black',
                               meanline_visible=True, fillcolor='lightseagreen', opacity=0.6,
                               x0='Total Bill'))

fig.update_layout(yaxis_zeroline=False)
fig.show()
```

This is the relevant section from my code. I have a number of traces so I'm using update_trace to set them all in one go.

```
figV.add_trace(go.Violin(y=dfNode['H_SEP'],
                        legendgroup='H_SEP', scalegroup='H_SEP', name='Head Sep',
                        line_color='#B233FF'))  
figV.update_traces(box_visible=True, meanline_visible=True,points='all')
```

This is what my version looks like. All the information is generated as standard by a violin plot, it's not text I've coded.  The numbers are also generated by the violin plot, so it's nothing I can round in my code. I want to keep all the information but I'd like each item to only have 2 decimal places. i.e. Head Sep, mean: 25.96.

[image]

Comment: @WilH There's a lot going on with hoverinfo in that violing plot. Would you care to include a screenshot to illustrate what you'd like to do. So far it seems to me that it's easy to edit some but not all of the information that is being displayed on hover.

Comment: @vestland I've added and image and a better explanation.

Comment: @Wilh Yep, that's what I thought... I haven't been able to crack that one. So +1 for that, and I hope someone else will be able to help you out.